# Using displayDialogAsync() to open dialog doesn't work after calling it a second time

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

When using displayDialogAsync() to open a dialog in Outlook, the dialog appears fine. However, when I close it with the 'X' button and try to reopen the dialog again by calling the same function, it does not work.

Looking at console logs, this error is thrown when attempting to reopen the dialog:

```
Callback cannot be specified both in argument list and in optional object.
```

How I'm calling displayDialogAsync:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(windowURL, LOGIN_DIALOG_OPTIONS, function (asyncResult) {    
_dialog = asyncResult.value;  
if (_dialog) {        
    _dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, onDialogMessageReceived);        
   _dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, onDialogEventReceived);    
}
});
```

I'm not sure what the error means, but I did try to call `_dialog.clearEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived)` as well as setting the dialog to null. Both of these approaches did not work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Outlook are you seeing this in?  The error seems to indicate that the options (LOGIN_DIALOG_OPTIONS) has a "callback" parameter.  Could you check the content of LOGIN_DIALOG_OPTIONS, on the 2nd call?   In my test, I can call displayDialogAsync multiple times and dialog opens as expected.

Comment: This happens in Outlook 2016 (Version 1701 Build 7766.2092) as well as Outlook for Mac 2016 (Version 15.36 Build 170620).  LOGIN_DIALOG_OPTIONS is just the config options without any callback function: LOGIN_DIALOG_OPTIONS = {
                            width: 35,
                            height: 75,
                            displayInIframe: true
                        };

Comment: Thanks for checking.  To help us confirm whether an unexpected parameter get inserted, could you please check the value of  LOGIN_DIALOG_OPTIONS in the debugger right before the 2nd call to displayDialogAsync?  It would also be interesting to try hard coding options and see if you get the same issue: Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(windowURL, { width: 35, height: 75, displayInIframe: true }, function (asyncResult) ...

Comment: That fixed it. Looks like the options object has to be a new object everytime displayDialogAsync is invoked. Thank you!